# Keyboard shortcut to move between highlighted fields in Visual Studio Code snippets?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I was trying to use the snippet completion for the Javascript "Array.prototype.forEach", which brings up a snippet with two highlighted fields (one for the array, and the second for the array element in the callback.) I can get through the first three steps depicted below, but I am at a loss for how to "tab over" to the last field.

Step 1: evoke the snippet by typing 
["forE"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPWV4.png)

Step 2: select the snippet from the dropdown menu, press Enter. [VSCode fills it in, highlights two fields, selects the first field and places the cursor at the end of the first field.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTHWQ.png)

Step 3: type the name of the array on which you want to execute the forEach function.[The generic label "array" is replaced](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfQX9.png)

Step 4: **[Need help here]** how do I select the next field? Using the mouse deselects all fields. Is there a keyboard shortcut I have missed in the documentation?

Steps taken thus far:

1. Reading VS Code documentation for Snippets (even that for Emmet and Emmet 2.0, in case this behavior was somehow governed by that).
2. Searching Stack Overflow
3. Searching Superuser (no similar questions found in either forum).

Comment: Waht do you mean by next field? Do you mean a shortcut to select the element keyword?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean.

Comment: Tab seems to do the job on my version of Visual Studio Code

Comment: tab works only if I haven't changed the "array" keyword yet. If I type out the array's name ("carts", in this case), and then press tab, VSCode deselects everything. I think I figured out a workaround, though. I press Enter, then Tab, and that seems to work. I imagine Enter is setting the array keyword to a value, then Tab is doing what is expected. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes I pressed enter and then tab. Your welcome!

Answer (score -1):

So, for the curious: The answer is:

Step 4: Press Enter. This exits the "label replacement for keyword" mode.

Step 5: Press Tab. This will select the next keyword field.

Special Thanks to @amicoderozer.